# How do I archive email using javax mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I need to archive/store a gmail email form java, but i only know set it on read/unread...

Here is my code :

```
public class CheckingMails {

private static Session session = null;
private static Store store = null;
private static Folder inbox = null;

   public static void check(String host, String storeType, final String user,
      final String password) 
   {
      try {
          Properties properties = new Properties();
          properties.setProperty("mail.host", "imap.gmail.com");
          properties.setProperty("mail.port", "995");
          properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "imaps");
          session = Session.getInstance(properties,new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
              protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                  return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
              }});
          store = session.getStore("imaps");
          store.connect();
          inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
          inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
          Message messages[] = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flag.SEEN), false));
          for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
              if(messages[i].getSubject().contains("Ticket#")){
                  System.out.println("Number of Ticket = " + messages.length);
                  messages[i].setFlag(Flag.SEEN, true);
              }

          }
          inbox.close(true);
          store.close();

      } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (MessagingException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
```

Can someone explain me how can i archive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by "archive it" you mean "move it to the archive folder on the server".

Use [Folder.copyMessages](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#copyMessages-javax.mail.Message:A-javax.mail.Folder-) to copy the message to the Archive folder, then mark the original message as DELETED using [Message.setFlag](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Message.html#setFlag-javax.mail.Flags.Flag-boolean-).